# memory (leaks) after executing

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks

I'm wondering why randomly after executing the ./a.out I get the following. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

[image: http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/8708/trasht.png]

http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/8708/trasht.png

Comment: Double frees can be very tricky/hard to trace for all but trivial programs. So, beware.

Comment: You are better off pasting your code, although I'm not sure who'd read 1024 lines of source :)

Comment: A picture of text. This is a first ... or is it... Obviously I haven't lived long enough yet.

Comment: Jeffrey... If you're gonna include the output of something like that, then include it as text. At least then someone could have fixed the formatting...

Answer (score 2):

As the error suggests you probably have a *double free()* or *heap corruption*

**Edit:** Either you're freeing the same buffer more than once or you're writing bytes in a memory region you shouldn't be writing to. The latter might be caused by writing in the buffer after freeing it or writing outside the buffer bounds.

Perhaps [Memcheck](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#memcheck) can help pinpoint the problem.

Compile your program with debug information `cc -g` and run `valgrind ./a.out`

Comment: so basically is because I'm freeing more times that I supposed to?

Comment: It is also possible that you are writing to memory that you are not supposed to be writing to.